# RecyclerView notifyDataSetChanged scrolls to top position

Tags: android, android-appcompat, android-recyclerview

when calling `notifyDataSetChanged` on `RecyclerView`  it doesn't retain the scroll position and scrolls to top, is there any solution to retain it's scroll position?

Comment: **DON'T** call `notifyDataSetChanged()` on the `RecyclerView`. Use the new methods like `notifyItemChanged()`, `notifyItemRangeChanged()`, `notifyItemInserted()`, etc...

Comment: I tried notifyItemRangeInserted(), but even that scrolls to the top. Any idea?

Comment: As @XaverKapeller said , I have used notifyItemInserted(),notifyItemRangeInserted, it works properly without scrolling the listview to the top.

Comment: @MohamedHatemAbdu what do you set into `notifyItemInserted` or `notifyItemRangeInserted` ?could you please explain your solution?

Comment: Please look at this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/49263790/5060269

Answer (score 19):

If your RecyclerView list item parent has "wrap_content" property, Recyclerview calculates the heights again and scrolls top.

There are two solutions:

1. Set your height a constant value like this: `layout_height="100dp"`
2. Use StaggeredGridLayoutManager like this:

   `mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new StaggeredGridLayoutManager(1, StaggeredGridLayoutManager.VERTICAL));`

The second solution is more efficient and I suggest this one

Comment: Yes, Recycler view calculates height in case of "wrap_content" so fix is setting fixed layout height or making height to "match_parent".

Answer (score 13):

Not sure if this solves your problem but I was having the same issue and it was because I was calling setAdapter after notify. So, not calling setAdapter after notify solved the problem.

```
mAdapter.notifyItemRangeInserted(mAdapter.getItemCount(), list.size() - 1);
recyclerView.setAdapter(); // remove this line. 
//Do this only when you're setting the data for the first time or when adapter is null.
```

Answer (score 3):

As I am guessing, what you are doing is resetting the adapter to the `RecyclerView` and then calling `notifyDataSetChanged().`

You need to pass only the `dataList` to the adapter by passing `dataList` in adapter method like adapter `update(dataList)`.
And in this method you can assign this list to adapter list like;

```
public void update(ArrayList<Hashmap<String,String> list){
  this.mList = list;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

[notifyItemChanged() make the RecyclerView scroll and jump to UP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36724898/notifyitemchanged-make-the-recyclerview-scroll-and-jump-to-up#answer-53011269)

```
android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
```

> Horizontal recyclerView inside vertical recyclerView generally causes that problem and this is best approach to get rid of problem. Don't put this attr into horizontal recyclerViews, it needs to be in only Parent (vertical RecyclerView).

Answer (score 1):

You can use [swapAdapter()](http://developer.android.com/intl/vi/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.html#swapAdapter(android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.Adapter,%20boolean)) and after call [notifyDataSetChange()](http://developer.android.com/intl/vi/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.Adapter.html#notifyDataSetChanged()). This works for me.

Answer (score 1):

RecycleViews will scroll back to the top on any variant of `notifyDataSetChanged` if they don't have a layout manager. Here's an example of how to set one.

```
LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(context, OrientationHelper.VERTICAL, false);
recycleView.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);
```

Comment: can you please help with this one
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58849910/how-to-stop-refreshing-recyclerview-data-scroll-to-top-position-android

Answer (score 1):

In my case, the recyclerview was paginated. Every time it reaches the end and loads/inserts item using notifyItemInserted, the recyclerView used to scroll. So following worked for me:

**`recycler_view.stopScroll();`**

As stated in the doc:

> Stop any current scroll in progress, such as one started by
>   smoothScrollBy(int, int), fling(int, int) or a touch-initiated fling.

Comment: My order was: 1 find target view's position 1.1 calc what position will have our view after inserting new data 2 save current view's top offset 3 swap adapter's data 4 call notifyDataSetChanged 5 call recyclerView stopScroll 6 call recyclerView scrollToPositionWithOffset with calced view's position and latest offset

Answer (score 1):

Use `scrollToPosition()` of recyclerView to scroll to the specific position. call this method after `notifyDataSetChanged()` by passing the length of adapter

```
arrayList.add(new ChatBotModalClass("aaaa","bbbb"));
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
recyclerview.scrollToPosition(adapter.getItemCount()-1);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"` in the parent recyclerView . It will fix the issue. I had a child recyclerView inside the parent recyclerView and this trick helped me. Also except first time you should always use notifyDataSetChanged on the adapter.

Answer (score -1):

You can't scroll to position without having set the adapter first. Set your adapter first, even if your list is empty. Update your list when you get the data. Then call adapter.notifydatasetchanged() method. You can then scroll to the last position. Let me know if this answers your question or if I have to put an answer – mmmcho

Answer (score -1):

This worked for me:

Set the fixed size property on the RecyclerView to "true" which prevents scroll up after calling notifyDataSetChanged on the adapter:

```
mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true)
```