# Problem with LiveData observer changing rather than staying the same

Tags: android, kotlin, android-livedata, mutablelivedata

I have a problems with a RecyclerView linked to LiveData. The RecyclerView content goes back up all the way to the top every time there is an update.

Apparently the problem lies in the way I created the adapter, as the Observer changes every time. Or so I understood. That observer is stuck inside a lambda, which is one of the many things I am still very remotely familiar with.

This is where the problem lies, apparently:

```
languagesViewModel.getLanguagesForUser().observe ( viewLifecycleOwner, { languages ->
        LANGUAGES_SCREEN_VIEWS.languagesRecyclerView.adapter = LanguagesRecyclerViewAdapter ( languages ) } )
```

I tried to get bits out of it, but it didn't work...

My first attempt was this:

```
var languageAdapter = LANGUAGES_SCREEN_VIEWS.languagesRecyclerView.adapter

languagesViewModel.getLanguagesForUser().observe( requireActivity(), { languages ->
            languageAdapter = LanguagesRecyclerViewAdapter(languages) } )
```

There was a warning that the variable is assigned but never accessed, and the list of languages is empty.

My second attempt was this:

```
    val languages = mutableListOf < LanguagesEntity > ()
    var languagesAdapter = LanguagesRecyclerViewAdapter(languages)

    languagesViewModel.getLanguagesForUser().observe( requireActivity(), { languages ->
        LANGUAGES_SCREEN_VIEWS.languagesRecyclerView.adapter = languagesAdapter } )
```

I hope it's clear that unfortunately I haven't got a clue of what I should really be doing. Not for lack of trying because I stabbed in the dark for three days before asking for help, and apparently that is the part of the code which is the problem. I do try to answer my own unanswered questions if I find a solution too. This time it just won't happen.

Comment: you might wanna check https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask
Your last statement before "Thank you very much in advance." is quite off.

Comment: Noted :-) It did come out of 2.00 am frustration, and a previous bizarre interaction on a related issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should have an `internal` function in `adapter` for setting value and notify the adapter.
And also, **DONT set your adapter** in `LiveData observer`.

You should consider this architecture.

Adapter

```
// STEP 1 - make a function to notify the variable
internal fun setLanguage(lang: List<LanguagesEntity>) {
       languages = lang
       notifyDataSetChanged()
 }
```

```
// STEP 2 - setup recyclerview before everything
val languages = mutableListOf < LanguagesEntity > ()
var languagesAdapter = LanguagesRecyclerViewAdapter(languages)
LANGUAGES_SCREEN_VIEWS.languagesRecyclerView.adapter = languagesAdapter 


// STEP 3 - set new value to adapter
languagesViewModel.getLanguagesForUser().observe( requireActivity(), { languages ->
    
    languagesAdapter.setLanguage(language)

} )
```

Hope it is clear to you.

Comment: I really can't see any difference here

Comment: You means you want 1 shot value only?

Comment: https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/recyclerview/widget/RecyclerView.Adapter#notifyDataSetChanged()
He will basically still experience the same result of data changing whenever the observer observe a change...perhaps via api call or something

Comment: notifyDataSetChanged() is too expensive when you can change the small part with changes only.

Comment: Actually you did a good job taking the Adapter Initialisation out of the Observer as expected!

Comment: Thank you. I do fully understand the solution :-) I wasn't just not familiar enough with kotlin and android yet to work it out by myself, but your answer is clear and it will help me learn more!

Comment: @Wale yes, thanks for mentioning it on expensive operation of ```notifyDataSetChanged()```

Comment: @Dan if you want a 1 shot value return from ```LiveData```, you may consider kotlin ```Flow```
https://developer.android.com/kotlin/flow

Comment: @Teo Thank you again! I am using Flow in the DAO, yes :-)