# androidViewModel + recyclerview scroll jump on model update (MVVM)

Tags: mvvm, android-recyclerview, viewmodel, android-viewmodel

I have a very specific issue with a recyclerview + mvvm implementation.

When I select a `ListItem` in the recyclerview, the click is given to my viewmodel class, which applies the "isselected" flag on the `ListItem` plus the `MutableLiveData` class that is observed (indirectly) by the recyclerview. This causes the observer in the mainactivity to update the whole `List<ListItem>` which is displayed by the recyclerview.

The result is that whenever I select an item in the recyclerview, the recyclerview will scroll up, (presumably) because the whole list is updated, and it treats the updated list as a whole new list.

How can this behavior be adjusted in a clean code, preferably mvvm pattern.

(Maybe a solution in which the position of the click was recorded, and the new list is "scrolled" to this position immediately, if the position exists. But I don't know how to implement this, if possible.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out this is a pretty common problem, but my search wording with google was misleading me.

This stackoverflow answer solved my problem:

[Refreshing data in RecyclerView and keeping its scroll position](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28658579/refreshing-data-in-recyclerview-and-keeping-its-scroll-position)

```
//add a Parcelable field to save the state
private Parcelable recyclerViewState;

//before updating the adapter with live data
recyclerViewState = recyclerView.getLayoutManager().onSaveInstanceState();

//after updating the adapter with live data
recyclerView.getLayoutManager().onRestoreInstanceState(recyclerViewState);
```