# ListView: Keep list item at same position after click

Tags: android, listview

When I (long)click an item in my **ListView**, some list items change their heights (as intended) and the clicked item suddenly moves (sometimes even out of view). How can I keep it under my finger?

By using *list.smoothScrollToPosition()*, I can only choose which item (by index) will be the topmost visible one.

*view.setTop()* (in pixels) doesn't seem to do anything.

I also tried *list.smoothScrollByOffset()* (in pixels), but then I need to know how much my item has moved. But unfortunately *view.getTop()* before redrawing is the same as *view.getTop()* after redrawing.

Any idea?

```
list.setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {
    public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        // some action changing the height of some list items
        notifyDataSetChanged();
        // How to bring the clicked list item back under my finger?
        return true;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for asking too quickly. After some more googling I found the solution [in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28658579/refreshing-data-in-recyclerview-and-keeping-its-scroll-position).

```
list.setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {
    public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        int top = view.getTop();
        // some action changing the height of some list items
        notifyDataSetChanged();
        list.setSelectionFromTop(position, top);
        return true;
    }
});
```