# Saving scroll position RecyclerView

Tags: android, kotlin, mobile, android-recyclerview

I have a problem with my recycler view scroll position. I used the solution from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28658579/refreshing-data-in-recyclerview-and-keeping-its-scroll-position) link.

```
  listViewModel.products.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer {
        val recyclerViewState = recyclerView.layoutManager?.onSaveInstanceState()
        listAdapter.setProductList(it)
        recyclerView.adapter = listAdapter
        recyclerView.layoutManager?.onRestoreInstanceState(recyclerViewState)
```

It works but it seems like If the scroll is sometimes in the wrong position, the view "jumps" a bit during refresh live data. What might be a problem?

My recycler:
[recycler](https://i.stack.imgur.com/as2Sw.png)

**EDIT**

I read that the problem is probably checkbox. So here's my impl:

```
inner class ListViewHolder(val binding: ItemListBinding ) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(binding.root), View.OnClickListener{

    fun bind(product: Product) {
       
        binding.checkBoxBought.isChecked = produkt.isBought == true
        }

    init{
         binding.checkBoxBought.setOnClickListener(this)
     }

    override fun onClick(p0: View?) {
         val position: Int = bindingAdapterPosition
         if (position != RecyclerView.NO_POSITION) {
             listener.onCheckBoxClick(position, binding.checkBoxBought.isChecked)
         }
     }
```

And fragment

```
 override fun onCheckBoxClick(position: Int, isChecked: Boolean) {
    val clickedProduct: Produkt = listAdapter.getProductByPosition(position)
    listaViewModel.updateProduct(clickedProduct, isChecked)

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Put this code in your adapter class, set check box true/false from adapter

```
yourCheckBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(null);
yourCheckBox.setChecked(/*Get True/Flase From Model*/);
yourCheckBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener((buttonView, isChecked) -> {
    //your check/uncheck code goes here....
}
```

Comment: Im not using onCheckedChangeListener. State of the checkbox depends on boolean value from database. I have implemented the on click function that updates that status. Everything happens in view holder class.