# ListAdapter, update items like notifyDataSetChange

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, listadapter

Is there any way to update `ListAdapter` items in a way that doesn't refresh the whole list?
For now, if you call `adapter.submitList(newITems)` **again**, it will scroll the list to the top again, not just replacing current items with new ones.

Comment: Clearly you have not implemented DiffUtil correctly, otherwise RecyclerView would have kept the topmost visible item with a matching ID visible. Include your class and your DiffUtil implementation.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, It is possible to update Adapter items in a way that doesn't refresh the whole list. Suppose you created an adapter and the name of the adapter is "**ListAdapter**".If you wanna update the adapter items that means you wanna change the value of a certain position. Here you just pass the position.

```
listAdapter.notifyItemChanged(position:Int)
```

Maybe you inserted values in a position,

```
listAdapter.notifyItemInserted(position:Int)
```

or you may remove a value from a position,

```
listAdapter.notifyItemRemoved(position:Int)
```

Answer (score 0):

As ianhanniballake mentioned, I was implementing the `DiffUtil` incorrectly. I was checking the whole new and old values in `areItemsTheSame` function, while should only check a unique field (like `id`).

```
    override fun areItemsTheSame(oldItem: FuelSubsidyEntity, newItem: FuelSubsidyEntity): Boolean {
        return oldItem.reportId == newItem.reportId
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

You can save the scroll position prior to calling `submitList()` and then restore it afterwards:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/32526482/7434090