# RecyclerView.Adapter.StateRestorationPolicy.PREVENT_WHEN_EMPTY stopped working

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, listadapter

Our app has a list of items, and an associated recycler view with it:

```
class Adapter(val clickListener: PreviewListener) :
    ListAdapter<DataItem, RecyclerView.ViewHolder>(EntryDiffCallback()) {
```

The adapter is set up in the `onViewCreatedMethod`:

```
private var previewAdapter: PreviewAdapter? = null

       if (previewAdapter == null) {
            previewAdapter =
                PreviewAdapter(
                    PreviewListener { info ->
                        previewViewModel.updateCurrentInfo(info)
                        findNavController()
                            .navigateSafely(
                                PreviewFragmentDirections
                                    .actionToExerciseFragment())
                    })
            previewAdapter?.stateRestorationPolicy =
                RecyclerView.Adapter.StateRestorationPolicy.PREVENT_WHEN_EMPTY
        }
        binding.previewListView.adapter = previewAdapter

        postponeEnterTransition()
```

The list is populated in the following manner:

```
previewViewModel.listItems.observe(
            viewLifecycleOwner,
            Observer { list ->
                previewAdapter?.submitList(list)
                (view.parent as? ViewGroup)?.doOnPreDraw { startPostponedEnterTransition() }
            })
```

When the user clicks on an item, it is taken to a new fragment, and when they press back, they end up in the main fragment again. However, the recycler view does not retain the position.

I have extensively read the internet:
https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/restore-recyclerview-scroll-position-a8fbdc9a9334
and stack over flow:
[Maintain/Save/Restore scroll position when returning to a ListView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3014089/maintain-save-restore-scroll-position-when-returning-to-a-listview)
[Refreshing data in RecyclerView and keeping its scroll position](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28658579/refreshing-data-in-recyclerview-and-keeping-its-scroll-position)
[RecyclerView store / restore state between activities](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28236390/recyclerview-store-restore-state-between-activities)

And tried some really funky solutions, yet none of these retain the recycler view in the old position when the user is returning back. (eg. PREVENT_WHEN_EMPTY, using SavedInstanceState on the layout manager, and remembering the scroll position).

I'm also using shared element to animate transitions

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        sharedElementEnterTransition =
            MaterialContainerTransform().apply {
                duration = resources.getInteger(R.integer.reply_motion_duration_large).toLong()
                scrimColor = Color.TRANSPARENT
                interpolator = DecelerateInterpolator()
                setAllContainerColors(requireContext().getColorFromAttr(R.attr.colorSurface))
            }
    }
```

I clean up the data on destroy view, and destroy, but removing these doesn't seem to do anything except cause CanaryLeaks:

```
    override fun onDestroyView() {
        super.onDestroyView()
        binding.previewListView.adapter = null
        _binding = null
    }

    override fun onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy()

        previewAdapter = null
    }
```

Any suggestions? Thank you

Comment: Can you explain why you have two separate variables - one called `adapter` and one called `previewAdapter`? You're setting the value of one of them, but setting the `stateRestorationPolicy` on the other one.

Comment: Oh gosh, I don't actually have two variables in the class (just double checked). I was trying to remove some verbose to make it fit better in one line, so I removed all identifying words.